# suid-root doesn't have effect

Tags: files, permissions, setuid

A program from [apue](http://www.apuebook.com/).

```c
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
        err_quit("usage: a.out <pathname>");

    if(access(argv[1], R_OK)<0)
        err_ret("access error for %s",argv[1]);
    else
        printf("read access OK\n");
    if (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) {
        err_ret("open error for %s", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("open for reading OK\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it to an executable named `4-2` and I changed the owner and set the suid this is the output of `ls -l`:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root sinners 8490 Jan  7 18:50 4-2*
```

and `/etc/shadow`:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 421 Jan  4 01:29 /etc/shadow
```

But when I run it:

```
user% ./4-2 /etc/shadow 
access error for /etc/shadow: Permission denied
open error for /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

Can someone explain why I am getting these `access` and `open` errors?

Comment: should i ask the question here or stack overflow?

Comment: Can you please provide the link or access to apue.h?

Comment: Also provide, OS details, GCC details

Comment: @Nikhil os:archlinux 3.1.6-1-ARCH gcc 4.6.2

Comment: @sinners Generally it's better to reply to requests for information by *editing your original question*, so that everyone can see it and not just people following the comments.

Comment: @jw013 i can't find the tag like [del][/del]。

Comment: @sinners I meant to add your OS and gcc information to your original question by editing it.  I am not sure what you mean by [del] tags?

Answer (score 7):

Quoting `access()` [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access):

> The check is done using the calling process's real UID and GID, rather
>   than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an
>   operation (e.g., open(2)) on the file. This allows set-user-ID
>   programs to easily determine the invoking user's authority.

Set-user-ID bit makes the process's *effective UID* equal to the file owner, but the real user ID remains unchanged (i.e. remains what it was before `exec()`).

You can use [`setreuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setreuid) to modify both effective UID and real UID of the process or you can use `open()` to determine privileges. I recommend the second solution especially since you already call `open()` anyway. You can check whether `errno` is equal to `EPERM` to find out whether insufficient permissions was the reason `open()` failed.

The call to `open()` fails in your code, because you use the return value from `open()` as the if condition. I guess the call actually succeeds and returns you a valid, non-zero (zero being already taken by stdin) file descriptor making the control go into the error-handling branch. The error-handling branch of the if displays `EPERM` error message since this is the last error which occurred due to `access()` call. The condition to enter the error handling branch should check whether `open()` returned -1.

Comment: @AdamZalcman thank you.i modified the question,i just want to ask the open error.sorry

Comment: @sinners I have added the explanation for the second error message (last paragraph).

Comment: @AdamZalcman i understand.thank you. i'm wrong,the book was right.